# doubly linked list illustration

Tags: linked-list

I'm trying to illustrate a doubly linked list problem.  this is from an old test i've been studying lately.

The question is as follows:

draw what the final linked after this code:

```
ListNode n1 = new ListNode();
ListNode n2 = new ListNode();
ListNode n3 = n1;
n1.next = n2;
n3.prev = n1;
n1.next.prev = n3.next;
```

Where I get lost is the final line of code.

n1.next.prev = n3.next;

here's the solution:

http://www.imagechicken.com/viewpic.php?p=1242322384048558300&x=jpg

can anyone walk me through this one or lead me in a good direction?

Comment: That line that you don't understand sets n2.prev to itself. All the nodes prev members point back to themselves. n1 and n3's next member points to n2. n2's next member is undefined.

Comment: I think you need to give a little more information on this question - I'm not sure what you're asking about?  Why don't you understand why n1.next.prev = n3.next works?  It this about the mixing of l-values and r-values (a major cause for confusion in learning about pointers)?   You have the right illustration linked (you could have included that in the question as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to this one is that n1 and n3 point to the same ListNode.

Here are the states after each of the 3 operations:

```
n1.next = n2;
// n1.prev = null;
// n1.next = n2;
// n2.prev = null;
// n2.next = null;
// n3.prev = null;
// n3.next = n2;

n3.prev = n1;
// n1.prev = n1;
// n1.next = n2;
// n2.prev = null;
// n2.next = null;
// n3.prev = n1;
// n3.next = n2;

n1.next.prev = n3.next;
// n1.prev = n1;
// n1.next = n2;
// n2.prev = n2;
// n2.next = null;
// n3.prev = n1;
// n3.next = n2;
```

So in that last statement, `n3.next` is the same as `n1.next`, which is `n2`. Thus, the last statement is equivalent to settings `n2.prev = n2`.

Answer (score 4):

Step one: Two nodes, not linked. `n1` is also known as `n3`.

```
      +-------+next        +-------+next
      |       +---->       |       +---->
  prev|   n1  |        prev|   n2  |    
 <----+   n3  |       <----+       |   
      +-------+            +-------+
```

Step two: `n1.next = n2;`

```
      +-------+next        +-------+next
      |       +----------->|       +---->
  prev|   n1  |        prev|   n2  |    
 <----+   n3  |       <----+       |   
      +-------+            +-------+
```

Step three: `n3.prev = n1;`
Since `n3` is `n1`, this turns the arrow around.

```
      +-------+next        +-------+next
      |       +----------->|       +---->
  prev|   n1  |        prev|   n2  |    
 /----+   n3  |       <----+       |   
 \--->+-------+            +-------+
```

Step four: `n1.next.prev = n3.next;`
Remember that `n1.next` is `n2`, and `n3` is `n1`. Follow the arrows:

```
      +-------+next        +-------+next
      |       +----------->|       +---->
  prev|   n1  |        prev|   n2  |    
 /----+   n3  |       /----+       |   
 \--->+-------+       \--->+-------+
```

So the `prev` pointers of `n1` and `n2` both end up pointing to themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I would try drawing three boxes.  Divide each box into thirds - one third for the label, one third for "prev", and one third for "next".  Then draw connecting lines from all the "prev" and "next" to the appropriate label to see how things are linked.

A picture can be worth a thousand words.

Comment: Two boxes would probably make it easier, since n1 and n3 are just different names for the same node.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing gets confusing, until you realize that there are only two INSTANCES of ListNode; n1, n2, and n3 are all referring to those instances.  And in particular, the values of n1, n2, and n3 are only set once; since the value of n3 is set to n1, you could just as easily replace n3 with n1 in this code, and it would work the same.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry -- could not make heads or tails out of the picture.

n1.next = n2. Therefor, n1.next.prev evaluates to n2.prev

n3 = n1. Therefore, n3.next evaluates to n1.next.

You are setting n2.prev to n1.next.